# How to execute a pre-set command in git bash

Tags: curl, automation, git-bash

I want to do a curl on git bash without having to type it out. I.e, I want to execute "`curl http://google.co.uk`" by running a batchscript in windows.

Is it possible to do this? I am trying this as I am trying to automate several curl requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great idea to use git bash for testing! If you want to invoke curl several times from a script, I'd use a bash script.

First create a file named `doit.sh`, and place your curl commands inside:

```
#!/bin/env bash

curl http://google.co.uk
curl http://www.google.com
# More as needed...
```

Save the file and you should be able to run it by double-clicking it in Windows Explorer - or even better, by running it with `./doit.sh` on the command line.

curl is a really powerful tool for this kind of testing, so if you're willing to go down the road of bash scripting you can write more sophisticated tests - for example:

```
#!/bin/env bash

expected_resp_code="200"
echo "Making sure the response code is '$expected_resp_code'..."

actual_resp_code=$(curl --silent --head --write-out %{http_code} http://www.google.co.uk/ -o /dev/null)

if [[ ! "$actual_resp_code" = "$expected_resp_code" ]] ; then
  echo "Expected '$expected_resp_code', but got code '$actual_resp_code'"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Success!"
exit 0
```

Executing your script in git bash might look like:

```
you@yourmachine ~/Desktop
$ ./doit.sh
Making sure the response code is '200'...
Success!
```

If you scale up to many dozens or hundreds of tests, you might want to consider moving to another scripting language, but for a few one-off tasks invoking curl from a bash script might serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach: any script called `git-xxx.bat` will be executed in a git bash session, even when called (`git xxx`) from a cmd DOS session, as long as `git-xxx.bat` is in a folder referenced by the `%PATH%`.

You could implement your `curl` commands in said script.